# IIS Folder being added to clickable row link bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, model-view-controller

For some reason bootstrap clickable row is adding in the sub folder of the iis website into the link when I click it you will see here my html here.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SOPItems)
{


            <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="Order" data-ono="@item.OrderNumber" data-ino="@item.ItemNumber" data-filter="@ViewBag.CategoryFilter">

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QtyOrder)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment1)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment2)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QtyDelivered)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QtyAllocated)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QtyOutstanding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerOrderNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StockCode)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartsCut)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TackedUp)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemNumber)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see here i have the website setup as a site.

[image]

Before i click the link its the correct path the link is in a table with the data as shown in the above html code.

[image]

However after I click the link its saying that it should be including the folder which is wrong how does clickable row work in the background how does it even no what page to go to?.

[image]

You will also see my routes here in case they are at fault as well.

Routes.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Filter",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{filter}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Filtered", filter = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "StockOrderDelete",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{filter}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "StockOrderDelete", id = UrlParameter.Optional, filter = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Order",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{oNo}/{iNo}/{filter}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Order", oNo = UrlParameter.Optional, iNo = UrlParameter.Optional, filter = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CustomerSearchResults",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{customer}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "CustomerSearchResults", customer = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "StockLevelCategories",
        //    url: "{controller}/{action}",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "StockIndex", customer = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);
    }
}
```

Now on the main site where it is installed its configured as an application but I have windows ten pro and iis 10 and I dont see the option to covert a site to an application unless I am missing something.

Can someone tell me how clickable row works and why its adding in the web.som which is the apps living folder.

IIS Version
[image]

Showing the live site configuration which works and resolves correctly. Intresting to note it has a virtual path property with the development version does not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For someone else who might find this useful check ur javascript files i found this lurking and it was appending the folder to the string. Once I removed that it was fine !. I hate programmers who hard code makes it so hard for other programmers to take over a project !.

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function () {
    debugger;
    var oNo = $(this).data("ono");
    var iNo = $(this).data("ino");
    var filter = $(this).data("filter");

    if (filter == -1)
    {
        return
    }

    var location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/Web.SOM/Home/" + $(this).data("href")+"?ono="+oNo+"&ino="+iNo + "&filter="+filter;
    window.document.location = location;

});
```